# Pyspark: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'lookup'

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, rdd

I have an RDD whose top 2 elements are as above:

```
    dataset_json = sc.textFile("data/my_data.json")
    dataset = dataset_json.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
    dataset.persist()
    dataset.take(2)
```

Output:

```
[{'movie': 'movie_name1',
  'release_date': '2011-01-11T10:26:12Z',
  'actor': 'actor_name1'},
 {'movie': 'movie_name2',
  'release_date': '2010-04-08T04:14:23Z',
  'actor': 'actor_name2'}]
```

I want to isolate the values related to the release date, but the line below returns:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'lookup'

```
    dataset2 = dataset.filter(lambda line: line.lookup('release_date')) 
    dataset2.first()
```

If I try to identify the key using the following code, the output returns the full dataset, instead of the keys only:

```
    attributes = dataset.filter (lambda x: x.keys())
    attributes.take(2)
```

It returns again the full dataset as output instead of the keys only:

```
[{'movie': 'movie_name1',
  'release_date': '2011-01-11T10:26:12Z',
  'actor': 'actor_name1'},
 {'movie': 'movie_name2',
  'release_date': '2010-04-08T04:14:23Z',
  'actor': 'actor_name2'}]
```

Can anybody explain me why the above code doesn’t work, and how I can isolate the release_date? (Final aim of this exercise would be to find the earliest release date).
Thanks!

Comment: What is your desired output? Are you looking for: `dataset.map(lambda line: line.get('release_date'))`?

Comment: Hi Paul, basically yes thanks! Also, ideally, an explanation of why my above code doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Your code doesn't work because each row is a `dict` and there is no `lookup` method for python `dict`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the values for the key 'release_date' just use a map

```
dataset.map(lambda x: x.get('release_date')).take(2)
# Out:
# ['2011-01-11T10:26:12Z', '2010-04-08T04:14:23Z']
```

Use a default value `get('release_date', 'some_default_value')` for for lines with missing 'release_date'.

To sort:

```
dataset.takeOrdered(2, key = lambda x: x.get('release_date'))
```

(but note that dates are compared as strings)

`lookup()` is a function that can be applied to an RDD. But in this case the RDD doesn't contain  key-value but dictionaries. One way to use `lookup` would be to flatten the RDD and make it into a key-value pairs RDD

```
dataset.flatMap(lambda x: x.items()).lookup('release_date').take(2)
# Out:
# ['2011-01-11T10:26:12Z', '2010-04-08T04:14:23Z']
```

In your example, you were trying to apply `lookup` to `line`, which is a dictionary and doesn't have a lookup method.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine! I was still wondering if anyone can explain why the way I implemented lookup doesn't work (and how could I make it work, just for the sake of my own knowledge). Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much again!